# Remap caps lock key on iPad keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I have a [Logitech Ultrathin Keyboard Cover](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/tablet-accessories/ipad/ultrathin-keyboard-cover) for my 3rd gen iPad, which is a Bluetooth keyboard. Is there any way to remap the caps lock key so it acts as the control key instead?

Comment: I've reported a bug to Apple asking them to allow this. It drives me nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by using the default software, there is not a way to do this.

Theoretically, someone could write an app for jailbroken iPads to do this, but I did some searching and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. In Blink shell (iOS application) it's possible to swap Ctrl and Caps Lock (or have Ctrl for both) for an attached keyboard. Maybe it's possible to write an application (a keyboard) which would allow this?

Anyway, in Blink it's possible. I use Emacs Org-mode remotely for taking notes etc., so it's really nice to have the option to map the Ctrl to Caps Lock.

Comment: @martinweiss You are correct — it is possible for an individual app to remap Caps Lock as Control, but there is currently no way to make this change system-wide.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to write a "keyboard" application that could do this. Anyway, since Ctrl isn't really used that much on Mac, I assume the mapping would be mostly relevant when working in a terminal (e.g., using Emacs). And for that, Blink is nice.

Comment: I use control all the time on iOS; control a is start of line, control d is forward delete character, etc.